# Can you solve this rebus puzzle 2?

Tags: rebus, language

Two separate words.

[image]

Can you solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First word is

> Linear because L in ear

The second might be

> Model because the diamond is the sign of "mod" in SE and "el" is "the" in Spanish.

So

> Linear model

Comment: (+1) You are correct! :)

Comment: Nice rebus! ;) I did struggle on the square thing.

Comment: Then definitely _language_ is also a definitely applicable tag